# Positioning coordinates in middle of map data tile?

Tags: here-maps

[image]

Above you can see an image tile which is generated based on a lat, lon position. As you can see that the generated image and data tile contains a lot of unnecessary mountain region. For getting the tile image, please refer to the following link:

https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/enterprise-map-tile/topics/key-concepts.html

Is there a way to generate a tile with the provided lat lon being in the middle of the tile?

Comment: By reading the documentation tiles have fixed extents. And obviously tile boundaries can be calculated with the formulas.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please edit the title of your question to include enough information for future visitors to be able to find this thread when looking for the same problem.

Comment: Please do not reference external images. Please ask only one question per Question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Caveat: yes it's possible, but it may take some work.

## Short answer

Map tiles have fixed extent. The tile at http://host/0/0/0.png (tile `z=0, y=0, x=0`) is a tile representing the extent of the entire planet. The tile at http://host/1/0/0.png is then one of the corners of the planet, and so on recursively. Map tile servers have these fixed extents deliberately: it enables a map server to cache requests for images of maps. If everyone was able to make a custom request with their own regions, then caching performance would suffer. It would take longer to render maps on the web, and a lot more server compute would be used rendering these images that might only be very slightly different from one that has already been requested. Therefore, map tile servers deliberately prevent you from giving your own region of interest.

## Caveat

Before we had slippy maps, we had (and still have) web map services (WMS). These aren't as performant as tile servers due to the aforementioned caching issue. WMSs allow a client to specify a request for a map *giving their own extent and image size*. This is really what you want. However you need a piece in the middle to translate from tiles to custom map extents. There are a few options for this:

- Desktop software (e.g. QGIS) allows you to give tile servers as hosts and will then make the correct tile requests for whatever map extent is in your current view. You could export this as an image.
- [MapProxy](https://mapproxy.org/) fills this niche, by providing a WMS server that *proxies* to tile servers. With MapProxy, you could start your own server that you make WMS queries to, and it would do the work of translating this to the appropriate tile requests, and then does clipping and any image transformation that might be required.
- It's also possible to do something rough yourself: instead of just getting one tile that intersects your point of interest, get all the tiles in the neighbourhood (picture a chessboard: you want one sqaure, and all of its "queen's case" tiles that are at most one space away). You could stitch these together and clip them to your appropriate extent.

The preferred option probably depends on your experience with programming, and how much automation you need.

Note that it also may depend on the policy of HERE Maps, I've kept this answer general to map tile servers because it's not limited to HERE Maps.

Comment: Thanks Richard, I believe in my case I will be more interested in using the technique of fetching neighborhood tiles. But that begs another question:

I do have the way to know current tile's extent, or boundary coordinates, but how do i use that information to fetch neighbor tiles in all four directions? 
What I know right now is the concept of Quad key search (https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/traffic/common/map_tile/topics/quadkeys.html). I will further explore this concept though but in the meantime if you have any specific link to share please do so.